# How do I set static variables in C++ classes?

Tags: c++, class, variables, static, member

I have a class like this:

```
class example {
public:
    static void setStaticVar() { example::var = 1; };
private:
    static int var;
};
```

But it gives me linker errors and I have no idea why.
I want to store some data in the variable that is the same for every instance. That's why I want to use a static variable instead of an instance variable (with an instance variable I would store the same data in every single instance of the class which is a waste of memory).

How do I do this?

Comment: example::var = 1; - that should be in .cpp file

Comment: [See here why](http://ideone.com/5QGUpV).

Answer (score 2):

In the source file

`int example::var = 0;`

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the variable *once*. In one `.cpp`, outside of any functions, you have to initialize the variable:

```
int example::var = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks. I did use static variables before, I just somehow forgot to do that :)

Answer (score 2):

You must initialize it out of the class definition.

Try this.

```
class example { ... };

// initialize it to avoid linker errors
int example::var = 1;
```

Comment: If that is in a header file that is included multiple places, you will get multiple definition errors.

Comment: That is correct. Typically static variables should be initialized in the `.cpp` files. That however isn't the case if you use header guards, which should be always.